# Non-jew standing under a chupah

Tags: halacha

Is a Non-Jew allowed to stand under a chupah when a wedding is being officiated, either as a guest or as a relative of the couple? Couldn't find a source that discusses this situation.

Comment: Interesting timing as [Liberal Judaism](https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/allowing-mixed-faith-weddings-under-the-chuppah-is-long-overdue/) in the UK just permitted intermarriage ceremonies to take place under the chuppah. r"l.

Comment: I don’t know the Halacha but practically what I’ve seen is that nonjews don’t stand under the chuppa that’s why they stand near but not under. However sometimes it gets complicated where the Kallahs father or Chossons father is not Jewish. As always CYLOR

Comment: @Robev as I understand it’s up to of the discretion of the rabbi whether to allow. It appears some don’t like the idea.

Comment: Possibly related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101657/non-jewish-family-in-an-orthodox-jewish-wedding

Comment: I assume halachically it's fine but for meta-halachic reasons it would be forbidden

Comment: I'd think non-Jewish photographers/videographers do it all the time, no?

Answer (score -1):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe says absolutely not: [image]

Comment: About what situation was he speaking? It's unclear. An intermarried relative?

Comment: "Should it materialize ..." -- so some family member's non-Jewish boyfriend/girlfriend/"date"?

Comment: If anything the letter says "as a spectator or guest" it would be okay.

Comment: What if either the groom or the bride (or both) are gerim? In which case it's not a situation of intermarriage but almost the opposite.

Comment: @Harel13 excellent! The letter above seems to be talking about some case that could be seen as sanctioning intermarriage.

Comment: I had to read this letter a bunch of times to make heads or tails about what he's talking about. My understand is someone asked if a non-Jew could attend their wedding. He  responded that what happens when this non-Jew hears "KeDas Moshe VeYisroel", and they figure out that Jews require Jews marrying Jews. What if this non-Jew is dating/married to a Jew? They'll feel bad, and realize that the other Jews at the wedding don't approve of their relationship. I don't really get why that's a problem, but then he says the Torah and Shulchan Aruch don't want them there...not sure why.

Comment: This is why Rav Moshe always restates the question (as he understood it, or at least wished to answer it). Otherwise you're left firmly convinced that the Rebbe prohibited **SOMETHING**. (Similar problem when they collected R' Hutner's letters.)

Comment: Wow, thank you Maurice Mizrahi! GREAT source! Couldn't be better! Really appreciate! Where can I find this letter?

Comment: @user16403 -- You mean where can you find it *online*?  Here is a source: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/1950151/jewish/A-Gentile-Under-the-Chuppah.htm